Permisos denegados al ejecutar un Script bash
de su apoyo para saber si a alguien le ha pasado este escenario:
Se esta utilizando Ubuntu server 20.04 y estoy tratando de ejecutar unos Scripts bash pero obtengo el error Permisos denegados cuando ejecuto de esta manera ./nombre.sh , mas sin en cambio si lo ejecuto de esta manera sh nombre.sh la ejecución se realiza de manera correcta, cabe mencionar que tiene los permisos necesarios y he repetido la operacion de varias formas como anteponer sudo y se repite el mismo escenario.
De su apoyo por si alguien tiene nociòn de que màs se puede revisar, de antemano muchas gracias.

No somos adivinos; publica el batch en cuestión (las primeras líneas bastan) y también muestra los permisos del archivo (ls -l nombre.sh)

Normalmente los archivos no tienen permiso de ejecución por defecto. Prueba dandoselo con chmod +x nombre.sh

Continuando con la revisión en varios medios sobre el problema indicado, les comparto que fue solucionado.
La raíz del problema fue el punto de montaje del File System donde se estaban ejecutando los Scripts ya que tenia la propiedad noexec aun continuo con la comprension del momento en que se modifico, gracias por la retro.

Yo tengo otra solución, ejecutando sudo su se pueden ejecutar todos los comandos que quieras.

Como ya lo pudiste resolver, podrías marcar tu respuesta como la correcta.

Normalmente los archivos recién creados no tienen permiso de ejecución por defecto. A excepción de los programas generados por un compilador que puedes ejecutar desde el primer momento.
Prueba dandoselo con chmod +x nombre.sh.
sh nombre.sh no requiere ningún paso adicional porque sh ya es ejecutable.
./nombre.sh ejecuta el script con el programa indicado en la primera línea del mismo, conocida como Shebang. Así que si esta línea no está presente el script no se ejecutará de esta manera.
Por cierto bash no es lo mismo que sh.

El otro cambio es poner #!/usr/bin/sh como primera línea en el script, para que no requiere indicar explicitamente bash script.sh

Gracias por la retro, si esta en cada Script considerado y el resultado es el mencionado anteriormente.
